# Selecting One Particular Data Item

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

I've created an Flex app. It currently has an drop down menu. With the option to select a Channel. Once the channel is selected the data pulls through. But, what I want to do is just pull through one channel of data as opposed to multiple items of data. How can I achieve this?

My code is quite simple at the moment and looks like this :

```
<mx:FormItem label="Select your Channel : " x="296" y="0">

    <s:DropDownList id="channelSelection" 
        dataProvider="{channelList.lastResult.channels.channel}" 
        labelField="name"  width="196"/>

</mx:FormItem>

<s:Label text="{channelSelection.selectedItem.name}"  x="298" y="35" width="331"/>
```

Comment: Hi Hering. Yeah what I want to do is scrap the dropdownlist all together and just have ONE item from my XML loaded in at once. A later adjustment to the app will work on the user selection, but just not at the moment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood you: Did you mean that you can use the dropdownlist just once to select a channel?

Comment: Use comments for asking clarifications.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow but there is no "add comment" visible for me in your post!?